# how to access to a sub-sub dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

If I want to evaluated a code fragment on pycharm I have the following :

```
fieldData['PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION']
>>> {'PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION': {'Security': 'OPTYWHKS Curncy', 'Position': 1.0}}
```

However if I try:

```
fieldData['PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION']['Security']
```

I get the following error :

```
>>> {TypeError}list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How can I have the values of the fields : 'Security' and 'Position' ?

To Elaborate a bit more fieldfata is in the following loop;

> ```
>                 if (fld in fieldData) and isinstance(fieldData[fld], list):
>                     if (fld =='PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION'):
>                         val =  fieldData['PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION']
>                         datum =[ticker,fld,val ]
>                         datum.extend(corrtype(fieldData['PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION'])Id)
>                         data.append(datum)
> ```

My goal is to put position and Security into a Dataframe

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct structure? seems like fieldData['PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION'] is returning a list

Comment: Are you sure this is indeed problem related to Python? Looks like problem with IDE itself.

Comment: Share full code with us. Just copy => paste

Comment: type(fieldData)  gives <class 'dict'>

Comment: type(fieldData['PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION']) gives <class 'list'>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your dict structure is something like:

```
fieldData['PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION'] = 
    {'PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION' : {'Security': 'OPTYWHKS Curncy', 'Position': 1.0}}
```

in which case you will need to access 'Security' like:

```
fieldData['PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION']['PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION']['Security']
```

To be able to access it with fieldData['PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION']['Security'], when you enter fieldData['PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION'] on the console it should look something like:

```
 {'Security': 'OPTYWHKS Curncy', 'Position': 1.0}
```

Comment: If I do fieldData['PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION']['PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION']['Security'] I still have the same typeError

Answer (score -1):

I have tried it and able to parse the requied.
PFB:

```
In [1]: a = {
        "PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION":
        {
            "Security": "OPTYWHKS Curncy",
            "Position": 1.0
        }
   }

    In [2]: a
    Out[2]: {'PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION': {'Security': 'OPTYWHKS Curncy', 'Position': 1.0}}

    In [3]: a['PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION']
    Out[3]: {'Security': 'OPTYWHKS Curncy', 'Position': 1.0}

    In [4]: a['PORTFOLIO_MPOSITION']['Security']
    Out[4]: 'OPTYWHKS Curncy'
```

Can you brief out the question a bit more if it is not the answer

Comment: Don't you know a Shell where a python code is executed.
If you don't understand better ask before down voting. Even I have given the same answer as above.